# Python Numpy Extract Array Elements Based on List of Index Values

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have the following numpy array:

```
X = np.array([1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1])
```

and I have a list of index values in list form:

```
idx_list = [0,4,5,8,9]
```

I want a numpy array with just the elements of the original array corresponding to those index values (in the same order).

So this is what I want:

```
X_sub = np.array([1,1,0,0,1])
```

I tried doing this:

```
X_sub = X[idx_list]
```

But got an error:

```
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce... The error seems from pandas

Comment: Same. Can't reproduce. Is this an error from pandas?

Comment: ````X = np.array([1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1])
idx_list = [0,4,5,8,9]
X_sub = X[idx_list]
X_sub```` This is working correctly for me.

Comment: As others mentioned, this error is seen in pandas, when trying to subset rows and columns. It generally requires `.loc()` or `.iloc()` to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  Stupid me.  It is pandas related.  Answer is as one of you suggested is to use loc/iloc.